# How to record/download m3u steam video from url using FFMPEG

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-recording, android-ffmpeg, m3u

I am trying to download video from m3u live stream but there is some part of video download

in this m3u8 url return segments and this segments merge and give video but video length is like one request response segments , i am try to download steam url but only 15 sec video will download.

how to continue download m3u8 using FFMPEG

URL i will try to download or record

http://cshms3.airtel.tv/PLTV/88888888/224/3221226049/index.m3u8

```
 String[] command = { "-y", "-i", INPUT_FILE,  "-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", dir.toString() + "/yourvideoname1.mp4"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like
`ffmpeg -i http://127.0.0.1/index.m3u8 -c copy output.mkv`

Comment: i am trying to download live steam continuous video , i try this code but full video is not download or record.

Comment: What if instead of using file, use typical pipe and load stream from pipe? I've not tried that, just an idea

Comment: thank you for answering.. but i did't get it what are you trying to say, can you please explain in simple way